# McAfee SiteAdvisor has a false positive on certain skeptics.SE questions

Tags: support, security

[McAfee SiteAdvisor seems to suggest](https://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/http%3A//skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/are-human-fetal-cells-used-to-produce-pepsi) that [this question](//skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/are-human-fetal-cells-used-to-produce-pepsi) on skeptics.SE is a security risk, and them it nags me that there is a risk. This happens for several other questions as well.

The [site report](http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/site/default.aspx?url=https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/are-human-fetal-cells-used-to-produce-pepsi) seems to say there is no risk, but McAfee keeps warning me every time I visit this question, and a few other questions.

[image: Screenshot of McAfee warning]

Comment: Same question on InfoSec SE: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142733/why-does-mcafee-think-stack-exchange-is-malicious

Comment: Retaliation for the rainbow banner

Comment: Obviously Pepsi is trying to cover up the truth.  Because nothing is more tasty then fetal cells.